# Could not find a part of the path 'c:\users\mehdi\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Grid\Grid\Data Files\'

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am getting this error "`Could not find a part of the path 'c:\users\mehdi\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Grid\Grid\Data Files\'.` when downloading a file saved in the above directory.Code for downloading is:

```
        protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton lnkbtn = sender as LinkButton;
        GridViewRow gvrow = lnkbtn.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
        string filePath = GridView1.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
        Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/Data Files/"));
        Response.End();
    }
```

Please help..

Comment: Creste the folder `Data Files` first and then run your code?

Comment: try `mkdir "c:\users\mehdi\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Grid\Grid\Data Files"` from a command prompt.

Comment: @rene Thanks for the prompt reply, can you please tell me what u mean by 'creste' ?

Comment: @rene I deleted the folder `Data Files` and used `mkdir "c:\users\mehdi\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Grid\Grid\Data Files"` to make a new folder. Still giving the same error.

Comment: `Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/Data Files/") + "afile.jpeg");` looks you're trying to send a complete folder...

Answer (score 0):

Try changing Server.MapPath("~/Data Files/") to Server.MapPath("~\Data Files\")